# Save file for more than one user at the same time

Tags: php

I am working on a CAPTCHA-system at the moment. For this I am creating random pictures with some basic math-problems on it. The user has to give the correct anser before submitting the form.

Here's the code:

```php
<?php
    function randExer() {
        //Creating random (simple) math problem
        $arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
        $item1 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $item2 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $random = $item1 . " + " . $item2;

        //Saving created math problem for later
        file_put_contents("../sites/exercise.txt", $random);

        //Creates a black picture with width=200 and height = 50
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);

        //uses RGB-values to create a useable color
        $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
        $silver = imagecolorallocate($img, 192, 192, 192);
        
        //Adds random lines to the images
        for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            imagesetthickness($img, rand(1, 3));
            $x1 = rand(0, 100);
            $y1 = rand(0, 25);
            $x2 = $x1 + rand(0, 100);
            $y2 = $y1 + rand(0, 25);
            imageline($img, $x1, $x2, $x2, $y2, $silver);
        }
        //Adds white-colored text
        $var = imagestring($img, 5, 18, 18, $random . " = ?", $white);

        $rotate = imagerotate($img, 10, 0);

        //Save image
        imagejpeg($rotate, "../sites/exercise.png", -1);    
    };
?>
```

As was pointed out in the comment on my [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/249036/contact-form-with-spam-prevention-follow-up) on Code Review, the system doesn't work, if more than one client uses the form at the same time, because the images will be saved in the same place.

How can this problem be solved without saving each picture with a different filename (I don't really want my server to be full of images)?

Comment: Use session data to store the correct score. (You also likely will find it easier to use one of the existing libraries for this, unless you must create your own)

Comment: @user3783243 Could you explain how that works?

Comment: When generating the page you must have something like `echo "what is $var1 + $var2?"`  so do `$_SESSION['captcha'] = $var1 + $var2;` on that same page generation. On the next page check if the submitted value equals the session value. After checking be sure to unset the session value so brute forcing can't be used.

Comment: @user3783243 Does this store the information in a cookie or on the serverside? If it stores it in a cookie:  Are there serverside alternatives?

Comment: The identifier would be in a cookie client side. The actual value would live server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this.

You could create a unique filename per user - that is per address and port using the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] variables to make a filename (possibly along with the time).

Note: port will change if socket is closed so if your client page isn't keeping a socket open over js, you will need to maintain a session id.  The session ID would need to be generated server side and stored on the client side until the client is ready to return it along with the verification.

You could make php take out semaphors for each client.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] ` is likely not guaranteed uniqueness. Multiple people can be behind `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` the port likely would make it a bit more unique but collisions could still occur.

Comment: Keeping the socket open is required to maintain uniqueness.  Similarly if you are generating a "random" session ID, you must keep track of these to avoid issuing the same one while a twin is active.